Prisms and the Fargues-Fontaine Curve
I am attempting to get a tourist's perspective on p-adic Hodge theory, and am confused about the precise relation between two very successful geometric interpretations of (different parts of) the story and their parallels with the archimedean stories developed by Simpson (which are much simpler and with which I'm much more familiar).
Simpson taught us to understand de Rham cohomology and the Hodge filtration on a complex variety X in terms of the de Rham stack $X_\text{dR}$ and its “deformation to the normal cone” $X_\text{Hod}$, which lives over $\mathrm{pt}_\text{Hod}=\mathbb A^1/\mathbb G_m$. Furthermore he taught us that real Hodge structures can (perhaps indeed should) be understood as real $\mathbb G_m$-equivariant vector bundles on the twistor $\mathbb P^1$, given by gluing two copies of $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb C}$ the usual way and with the real structure given by the antipodal map.
In the setting of rational p-adic Hodge theory, we are exhorted to think of p-adic cohomology theories (for a scheme $X$ over $\mathbb Q_p$) in terms of vector bundles on the Fargues–Fontaine curve, a p-adic analog of the twistor $\mathbb P^1$.  On the other hand in integral p-adic Hodge theory for a p-adic formal scheme we are taught to think in terms of perfect complexes over the Witt–Cartier stack AKA absolute prismatic stack $\operatorname{Spf}(\mathbb Z_p)^\Delta$ and its Nygaard-filtered version, a p-adic analog of $\mathbb A^1/\mathbb G_m$ (judging from a cursory glance at Bhatt's course notes on Prismatic F-gauges). These complexes can be constructed, in parallel to Simpson's story with $X_\text{dR}$ and $X_\text{Hod}$, as pushforwards of the structure sheaf of the prismatization $X^{\Delta}$ and its filtered version. Another key player is the syntomic stack, given by gluing together two copies of the filtered prismatic stack along two embeddings of the prismatic stack (which loosely suggests to the p-adically untrained mind a parallel with the twistor construction).
If I haven't butchered the analogy completely, it suggests that the rational version (generic fiber) of the absolute syntomic stack (or one of its variants) is some kind of quotient of the Fargues–Fontaine curve, presumably involving its Galois action, providing a geometric explanation of the relation between the two stories. [OR conversely, is there an integral version of the Fargues–Fontaine curve that maps eg to the syntomic stack?] If this is not completely off base and wrong-headed some version of it must be well known but I couldn't find a statement of this flavor in my googling. Or is there another preferred intuition for how the two stories relate?

Great question+1. Do you have a good reference for the story over $\mathbb{C}$? Especially for the deformation to normal cone.

I believe the 'correct' analytic analogue of the syntomification of something like $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is still being worked out. For now, the FF curve and its relative counterparts are defined for all perfectoid inputs. Given such $R$, we have the tilt $R^\flat$, and the FF curve is obtained by taking the adic space associated with $W(R^\flat)$, removing the vanishing locus of $p$ and a pseudouniformizer for $R^\flat$, and taking the quotient by Frobenius.

You can interpret $W(R^\flat)$ as the absolute prismatic cohomology of $R$. It has a filtration by power of the principal ideal of a surjection $W(R^\flat) \to R$, and one can take the associated Rees stack. This is the filtered prismatization. The two open embeddings of the prismatization are now given by: a) forgetting the filtration, b) taking the Rees stack for the doubly infinite filtration given by powers of the Frobenius twist of the kernel. The syntomification is produced from gluing these two opens together.

After inverting a generator for the kernel (one now has to leave the realm of formal geometry), this construction is essentially giving an integral version of the relative FF curve.

@KeerthiMadapusi Thanks so much for your comments! My ignorance prevents me from knowing if this even parses grammatically, but are you saying [a stronger integral version of] something like, if we work relative to a perfectoid (so "sufficiently locally"?) then the Fargues-Fontaine curve IS the analytic generic fiber of the syntomification?  That would be a wonderfully clear answer to my question.

@Andy Simpson's papers on the subject are wonderfully clear, eg https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9604005 for the Hodge filtration and https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9705006 for twistors. You can also see the discussion in Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum's book in terms of deformation to normal cone in DAG.

@DavidBen-Zvi Something like this is true, but the meaning of 'generic fiber' here is a bit funny. If $R$ is a complete valuation ring, $W(R^\flat)$ is something like a two-dimensional space with one direction along the spectrum of the char $p$ valuation ring $R^\flat$ and another in the Witt direction (you can think of $p$ as the 'coordinate' for this direction). What one has to do to get the integral FF curve from the syntomification is to essentially invert the Teichmuller lift of a topologically nilpotent element of $R^\flat$. The FF curve itself is then obtained by further inverting $p$.

In any case, there is certainly a map from the FF curve to something like the analytification of the syntomification, though one probably has to be a little careful about the world in which the latter lives. Camargo's talks on his work with Le Bras, Scholze and others (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B076k82McTc&list=PLnqZnMvF_Uaoyv0oqKvwlepWhahyk7jIq&index=1) might be helpful, though so far they only seem to give analytic analogues of the prismatization, and not yet for the other cohomological stacks.

@KeerthiMadapusi thanks so much! if you'd like to submit this as a response I'd be happy to accept. In any case will try to write an impressionistic summary.

@DavidBen-Zvi Sorry took me a while, but I've added these comments as an answer below

This is just a summary of my comments: For perfectoid rings $R$, the prismatization can be identified with the affine formal scheme $\mathrm{Spf}~W(R^\flat)$ where $R^\flat$ is the characteristic $p$ tilt of $R$. The topology here is the $(p,\xi)$-adic topology, where $\xi$ is a generator of the kernel of a surjection $\theta:W(R^\flat)\to R$ that is the usual one showing up in $p$-adic Hodge theory. We can equip $W(R^\flat)$ (also usually denoted $A_{\mathrm{inf}}(R)$ to emphasize the untilt $R$) with the $\xi$-adic filtration. The corresponding Rees stack can then be identified with the filtered prismatization of $R$; see Proposition 5.5.8 of Bhatt's lecture notes. The two copies of the prismatization here are obtained by: a) forgetting the filtration, b) taking the Rees stack of the two-sided $\varphi(\xi)$-adic filtration on $W(R^\flat)$. In the second case, the map to the filtered prismatization is basically given by the Frobenius lift on $W(R^\flat)$.
On the other hand, the relative Fargues-Fontaine curve is obtained by taking the adic space associated with $W(R^\flat)$ (a little care is needed here), removing the locus of vanishing of $p$ and a Teichm"uller lift $[\varpi]$ of a topologically nilpotent element of $R^\flat$, and then taking the quotient by Frobenius.
Now, let us return to the filtered prismatization. When one inverts $[\varpi]$ (in whatever the correct sense of this is), one also ends up inverting $\xi$, and so the Rees stack giving the filtered prismatization becomes the trivial deformation, and the difference between the two open embeddings of the prismatization is just Frobenius. In other words, the gluing together along the two open immersions now simply becomes an identification with the Frobenius twist. The syntomification therefore now becomes the integral version of the FF curve where we invert $[\varpi]$ but not $p$.
To get an analogous picture say for the $p$-completions of smooth $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebras (like $\mathbb{Z}_p$!), one would have to at least explain what the correct analogue of the FF curve should be for qrsp (quasiregular semiperfectoid) rings, since these are exactly the kinds of objects that show up when attempting to do fpqc descent along perfectoid covers. Camargo's talks on his work with Le Bras, Scholze and others (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B076k82McTc&list=PLnqZnMvF_Uaoyv0oqKvwlepWhahyk7jIq&index=1) might be helpful, though so far they only seem to give analytic analogues of the prismatization, and not yet for the other cohomological stacks.
